# Python: "unexpected end of regular expression" in searched text

Tags: python, regex

The following code gives me an error: "unexpected end of regular expression"

```
import re
my_text = "[abc"
if re.search(my_text, "a"):
    print "found!"
```

It's because of the single square bracket in my_text. This works fine:

```
my_text = "[abc]"
```

First of, I don't see why a single bracket should be a problem at all. The unmatched bracket is not in the regular expression, but in the string that is being searched.

I can escape the bracket:

```
my_text = "\[abc"
```

but are there other solutions? I'd prefer to not mess with the length of the string since I also do stuff like my_text[some_index:]

Comment: An open bracket has special meaning in a regular expression. If it doesn't have a matching close bracket, the regex is invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) function accepts the pattern as the first parameter and the actual string as the second parameter. The function signature is as follows

```
re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

So, just change the order of the parameters.

```
import re
my_text = "[abc"
if re.search("a", my_text):
    print "found!"
```

But the simplest way to check the existence of the string in other string is to use the `in` operator, like this

```
print "fourth" in "thefourtheye"  # True
```

Quoting from the Notes section of [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

> When s is a string or Unicode string object the in and not in
>   operations act like a substring test. In Python versions before 2.3, x
>   had to be a string of length 1. In Python 2.3 and beyond, x may be a
>   string of any length.

Comment: Doh! Thanks! I have used re.search correctly at least 25 times in my code and seem to have suddenly spaced. (I need to use regexp because it's actually searching for "[a-zA-Z]" )

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're thinking that the second argument of the [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) is the regular expression pattern.

No, the first argument is the pattern, and the second argument is the string.

Following is the signature of the [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) function:

> ```
> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
> ```

---

BTW, you don't need to use regular expression to check string inclusion. Use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) operator.

```
>>> "a" in "[abc"
True
>>> "d" in "[abc"
False
```